# SuiteScript Load Saved Search And Add A Filter Throws An Error

Tags: suitescript, suitescript2.0

I am loading a saved search in a suitelet. My code is;

```
systemId = params.system;

var itemSearchSet = search.load({
    id : 'customsearch253',
});

itemSearchSet.filters.push(search.createFilter({
    name: 'itemid',
    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
    values: [systemId]
}));
return itemSearchSet.run().getRange({"start": 0, "end": 1000});
```

This throws an error of "org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function _clone in object and. (N/search/searchObject.js#636)"

However if I comment out adding the new filter, it works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a variable. Like

```
var searchFilters = itemSearchSet.filters;
searchFilters.push(search.createFilter({
                    name: 'name',
                    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
                    values: [systemid]}));

itemSearchSet.filters = searchFilters;
```

Comment: I haven't no I will try that asap :)

Comment: Thanks for your help; with the above change I am getting the error "Wrong parameter type: filters[1] is expected as Filter

Comment: Yeah I tried that, still no luck. Getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to push the filter then run.

```
var itemSearchSet = search.load({
    id : 'customsearch253',
});
var searchFilters = itemSearchSet.filters;
searchFilters.push(search.createFilter({
                    name: 'name',
                    operator: search.Operator.ANYOF,
                    values: [systemid]}));
return itemSearchSet.run().getRange({"start": 0, "end": 1000});
```